# Network Link Conditioner doesn't work on localhost (but does on external websites)

Tags: networking, macos, firewall, xcode

I read in a few places people saying Network Link Conditioner is supposed to work on localhost. However I never managed to get it working. It works for any of my external communications. If I use it and connect to another machine on my local network, it works.

But if I try listening on 127.0.0.1 and connecting to 127.0.0.1, I don't get any latency. I tried testing my code with clumsy on a windows machine and it works as expected.

I'm using a custom UDP based protocol, if than can help. I'm not sure where to begin with this, google hasn't returned anything. I tried checking my firewall, but I'm not sure what to check for. Did this happen to anyone else? Thanks a bunch for any solution or any tip to get me in the right direction :)

Comment: What version of NLC? What version of macOS? NLC often breaks between major OS revisions, so if you haven't installed a fresh copy of NLC since you last installed a new major version of macOS, you should do so now. That's always the first step in NLC troubleshooting.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I'm on macOS 10.15.7

NLC is at version 2.0 (from what I can see in the finder). If I open package content and look at version.plist it says BuildVersion 9997.

I tried uninstalling it (remove from pref pane), restarting my computer, downloading Additional Tools for Xcode 12 (released April 5th 2021 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and reinstalling it with the same results.